# Messy output from urllib.request.urlopen() in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

in python2 code below gives a readable output

```
url = 'http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup'
source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
print source
```

while in python 3, this code:

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup").read()
print(url)
```

gives unstructured and incomplete version of the former. 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong or not doing?

Comment: what is the `type` of the `url` in python3 code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'unstructured and incomplete' you mean that the source of the page is printed in what seems to be one line, rather than in the structure it is on the page source.

You'll see that the output string is prefixed by a `b`, i.e. this is is a bytes literal. You need to decode it first

```py
url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup").read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: thank you! spent some time and by accident came across decode myself as well. That worked

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 the read() function returns a so-called byte literal (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).

When you check the 'url' variable's type: `print(type(url))` returns: `<class 'bytes'>`

You can convert it to an UTF-8 string with the decode() method:

```
print(url.decode("utf-8"))
```